How to simulate a HTML button press on other tab while being in another tab without switching tabs
I want to make a tampermonkey script that presses a button with "next" id (button id="next") on youtubePlaylistRandomizer website when I press a specific key combination. I want it to work even if I am on another tab.I don't want to switch tabs, simulate the press and return to my tab back again.
I tried making a script while getting help from Google Gemini. I could do it but it only worked when I was on that tab.
I tried to adding a thing to local storage with one script whenever i pressed my key combination(Alt + N). Then tried to read local storage every second and do the click on button thing when I had the thing in the local storage. But it still didn't work except only if I were on that tab.

But it still didn't work except only if I were on that tab. <-- That is by design. Only the active tab's code will execute.

You will have to fake the active status of the page by overriding the methods used by the site to detect it.

Understood! Thanks! I will try to simulate that the tab with the button is active and try my script again. I'll inform you if it worked...
